# Inverse Laplace Transform of $ \left(\frac{1-s^{1/2}}{s^2}\right)^2$

Tags: inverse, laplace-transform

I found this question in my N.P Bali's Engineering Mathematics 7th Edition.
I could not find any solved questions related to this.

How can I find the Inverse Laplace Transform of :

$\left({1-s^{1/2} \over s^{2}}\right)^2$

I know only to find the inverse Laplace of $s$ when the power is a whole number.

The answer to the question is given as : $\dfrac{t^3}{6} + \dfrac{t^2}{2} - \dfrac{16t^\frac{5}{2}}{15 \pi^{\frac{1}{2}}}$

I want to know how to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
With $\ds{\gamma > 0}$:
\begin{align}
&\int_{\gamma - \ic\infty}^{\gamma - \ic\infty}
\pars{1 - {s^{1/2} \over s^{2}}}^{2}\expo{st}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=\overbrace{\int_{\gamma - \ic\infty}^{\gamma - \ic\infty}
\expo{st}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\ds{0}}\ -\
2\color{#c00000}{\int_{\gamma - \ic\infty}^{\gamma - \ic\infty}
{\expo{st} \over s^{3/2}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}}\
+\
\overbrace{\int_{\gamma - \ic\infty}^{\gamma - \ic\infty}
{\expo{st} \over s^{3}}\,{\dd x \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\ds{\half\,t^{2}}}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#c00000}{\int_{\gamma - \ic\infty}^{\gamma - \ic\infty}
> {\expo{st} \over s^{3/2}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}}
> \\[3mm]&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\left\lbrack%
> -\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon}{\expo{xt} \over \pars{-x}^{3/2}\expo{3\pi\ic/2}}\,
> {\dd x \over 2\pi\ic}
> -\int_{\pi}^{-\pi}{\exp\pars{t\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}} \over \epsilon^{3/2}\expo{3\ic\theta/2}}\,{\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}\ic
> \,\dd\theta \over 2\pi\ic}
> \right.
> \\[3mm]&\phantom{\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\bracks{.}}\left.
> -\int^{-\infty}_{-\epsilon}{\expo{xt} \over \pars{-x}^{3/2}\expo{-3\pi\ic/2}}\,
> {\dd x \over 2\pi\ic}
> \right\rbrack
> \\[3mm]&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\bracks{%
> -\,{1 \over 2\pi}\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}x^{-3/2}\expo{-xt}\,\dd x
> -{2 \over \pi}\,\epsilon^{-1/2}
> -\,{1 \over 2\pi}\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}x^{-3/2}\expo{-xt}\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{1 \over \pi}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\bracks{%
> \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}x^{-3/2}\expo{-xt}\,\dd x - 2\epsilon^{-1/2}}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{1 \over \pi}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\bracks{%
> 2\epsilon^{-1/2} -
> 2t\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}x^{-1/2}\expo{-xt}\,\dd x - 2\epsilon^{-1/2}}
> ={2t \over \pi}\,{1 \over t^{1/2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-1/2}\expo{-x}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&={2 \over \pi}\,t^{1/2}\Gamma\pars{\half}={2 \over \pi}\,t^{1/2}\root{\pi}
> =\color{#c00000}{{2 \over \root{\pi}}\,t^{1/2}}
> \end{align}
>   $\ds{\Gamma\pars{z}}$ is the
>   [Gamma Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and
>   $\ds{\Gamma\pars{\half} = \root{\pi}}$

$$\color{#00f}{\large%
\int_{\gamma - \ic\infty}^{\gamma - \ic\infty}
\pars{1 - {s^{1/2} \over s^{2}}}^{2}\expo{st}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
=\half\,t^{2} + {2 \over \root{\pi}}\,t^{1/2}}
$$

> The OP changed the question after I solved it !!!.

Comment: @Amzoti I was one who edited the post. However, I just put $\tt{\verb=\left=}$ and $\tt{\verb=\right=}$ to adjust the $\left(\phantom{A}\right)$'s sizes. Any way, the OP has two problems instead of one which should be better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The partial fraction expansion yields;

$$\left(\dfrac{1-s^{1/2}}{s^{2}}\right)^2 = -\dfrac{2}{s^{7/2}}+\dfrac{1}{s^4}+\dfrac{1}{s^3} $$

Using this [*table of Laplace Transforms*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf) (item $6$ and item $3$ (twice)) yields:

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1} \left(-\dfrac{2}{s^{7/2}}+\dfrac{1}{s^4}+\dfrac{1}{s^3}\right) = -\dfrac{2 \times 2^3}{1 \times 3 \times 5 ~ \sqrt{\pi}}t^{5/2} +\dfrac{t^3}{6} + \dfrac{t^2}{2} = -\dfrac{16}{15~ \sqrt{\pi}}t^{5/2} +\dfrac{t^3}{6} + \dfrac{t^2}{2}$$

Comment: So the answer to the question is "look up in a table"? Are you serious?

Comment: Since there are no changes or explanations how the answer in the tables appear, it is clear -1.